# Why Entropy to be defined as Joint Probability Distribution Sum?

Tags: randomness, entropy, probability

From Stinson's book, during the demonstration of the following Theorem which says:

> $H(X,Y) \leq H(X) + H(Y)$, with equality if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

The author says to assume $X$ to take the values $x_i$, $i$ in the interval from 1 to m, and $Y$ to take the values $y_j$, $j$ in the interval from 1 to n, he denotes $p_i = \Pr[X=x_i]$, $i$ from 1 to m, and $q_j = \Pr[Y=y_j]$, $j$ from 1 to n. Then, he defines $r_{ij} = \Pr[X = x_i, Y = y_j]$, $i$ from 1 to m and $j$ from 1 to n, my question is:

why is $$p_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n} r_{ij}$$

and $$q_j = \sum_{i=1}^{m} r_{ij}$$

I would like a detailed demonstration. I would also like to comprehend better what $H(X,Y)$ means.

Comment: The author that says it is Stinson.

Answer (score 3):

First note that the the comma in the proability is the AND operator; $$ \Pr[X = x , Y = y] = \Pr[X = x \wedge Y = y]$$ This is common notation to simplify the writing.

Now, explicitly write as

$$p_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n} r_{ij} = \Pr[X = x_i \wedge Y = y_0] + \Pr[X = x_i \wedge Y = y_1] + \cdots + \Pr[X = x_i \wedge Y = y_m]$$

Since the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent then this is just a partition of the event $x_i$ by the random variable $Y$.

As a solid case, consider two dices; one has the $X$ and the other is the $Y$ as their random variable representing the upper value of the dice. In total there are 36 possible equal values of the two dice roll. Fix the first one, let say $3$ then

\begin{align}\Pr(X=3) = & \Pr(X=3,Y=1)+\\
& \Pr(X=3,Y=2)+\\
& \Pr(X=3,Y=3)+\\
& \Pr(X=3,Y=4)+\\
& \Pr(X=3,Y=5)+\\
& \Pr(X=3,Y=6)\\
= &\frac{1}{36}+ \frac{1}{36}+ \frac{1}{36}+ \frac{1}{36}+ \frac{1}{36} +\frac{1}{36} = \frac{1}{6}
\end{align}

---

$H(X,Y)$ is actually the [Joint Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_entropy) and the formula is given by (again the AND);

$$H(X,Y) = -\sum_{x\in\mathcal X} \sum_{y\in\mathcal Y} P(x,y) \log_2[P(x,y)]$$

In our context this is

$$H(X,Y) = -\sum_{x\in X} \sum_{y\in Y} P(X=x,Y=y) \log_2[P(X=x,Y=y)]$$

$H(X,Y)$ is simultaneous evaluation of $X$ and $Y$ and that is equal to first evaluating $X$ then given value of $X$ evaluate the $Y$

$$H(X,Y)= H(X|Y)+H(Y)=H(Y|X)+H(X) $$

Proving this bit long;

\begin{align}
H(X,Y) & = − \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \Pr(X=x_i,Y =y_j) \log \big( \Pr(X=x_i,Y =y_j) \big)\\
 & = − \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \Pr(X=x_i,Y =y_j) \log \big( \Pr(X=x_i) \Pr(Y|X = y_j|x_i) \big)\\
 & = − \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \Pr(X=x_i,Y =y_j) \big[ \log \big( \Pr(X=x_i) \big) +  \log \big( \Pr(Y|X = y_j|x_i) \big) \big] \\
 & = − \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \sum_{j=1}^m \Pr(X=x_i,Y =y_j) \right) \log \big( \Pr(X=x_i) \big) \\
   & - \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \Pr(X=x_i,Y =y_j) \log \left( \Pr(Y|X = y_j|x_i) \right)\\
 & = H(X) + H(Y|X)
\end{align}

Comment: This shouldn't be $\Pr(X=x_i) \Pr(X|Y = x_i|y_j)$ ?

Comment: Which line are we talking?

Comment: Line two after "Proving this bit long;".

Comment: $\Pr(X \wedge Y) = \Pr(Y | X) \Pr(X) = \Pr(X | Y) \Pr(Y)$

Comment: But how do you know they are equal?

Comment: [Conditional probability as an axiom?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#As_an_axiom_of_probability)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132829/discussion-between-joao-victor-melo-and-kelalaka).

Answer (score 1):

Entropy does not depend on what the "labels" or values of the random variable is, it is a property ONLY of the distribution. After all you just use $P(x), P(y), P(x,y)$ etc in the formula not $x,y$.

Once you realize this, the set of probabilities $P(x,y)$ is all you need to use and apply the original definition of entropy for a single random variable. If you like, define a vector random variable $z=(x,y)$ and compute its entropy as
$$
-\sum_{z} P(z) \log P(z)
$$
which is the same as computing
$$
-\sum_{x,y} P(x,y) \log P(x,y)
$$
This also means that the joint entropy of a number of random variables $H(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=H(p_1,\ldots,p_n):=H_0$ with $P(x_i)=p_i,$ is the same as the entropy of any reordering (permutation) of the joint distribution so this means

$$
H(p_{\sigma(1))},p_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,p_{\sigma(n)})=H_0
$$
for all permutations
$\sigma:\{1,\ldots,n\}\rightarrow \{1,\ldots,n\}.$